# Cannot stop ant from generating compiler Sun proprietary API warnings

Tags: java, ant, warnings, javac

I call javac from my ant script like this:

```
<javac srcdir="src" 
   destdir="build/classes" source="1.6" 
   target="1.6" debug="true" encoding="Cp1252"
   nowarn="true">
```

But it still throws compiler warnings in the output:

```
[javac] Compiling 73 source files to C:\IKOfficeRoot\Java\ERP\Framework\build\classes

[javac] C:\IKOfficeRoot\Java\ERP\Framework\src\de\ikoffice\util\LoggerFactory.java:49: warning: sun.reflect.Reflection is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[javac]         return Logger.getLogger(Reflection.getCallerClass(2));
[javac]                                 ^
[javac] Note: C:\IKOfficeRoot\Java\ERP\Framework\src\de\ikoffice\db\SingleShotResultSet.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 1 warning
```

I also tried

```
<compilerarg line="-Xlint:-unchecked -Xlint:-deprecation"/>
```

and

```
<compilerarg value="-Xlint:none"/>
```

but this has no effect either. How to I remove the warnings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I suppress javac warnings about deprecated api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554538/how-can-i-suppress-javac-warnings-about-deprecated-api)

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE! I already know how to get rid of deprecation warnings. I need to get rid of the unsafe-api-warnings now!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppress javac warning "...is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855700/suppress-javac-warning-is-internal-proprietary-api-and-may-be-removed-in-a-f). This one is earlier, but I'd rather stick to the one that does not mention Ant: what matters is javac

Answer (score 14, accepted):

adding the `-XDignore.symbol.file` option to the `javac` command line worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to do this is to use the `sunapi` suppression, i.e. either `-Xlint:-sunapi` for the entire compile, or `@SuppressWarnings("sunapi")` at your required scope.

Note, the only way to use this suppression though, is to first enable it with the compiler option `-XDenableSunApiLintControl`

[enableSunApiLintControl](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-langtools/blob/master/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Check.java#L113-L128)

Comment: Worked for me, thank you! Compared with other solutions I found, this one does not require to fork the compiler from gradle.

Comment: Yes this also got ride of everything despite what other sources have said. Big relief.

Comment: Basically works, got rid of the warning but I still see "Notes" that say the same.

Answer (score 2):

use nowarn attribute see below

e.g.

```
<javac srcdir="src" 
   destdir="build/classes" source="1.6" 
   target="1.6" debug="true" encoding="Cp1252"
   nowarn="on">
```

by default nowarn attribute is off

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot do that**: Neither from the command line, so you cannot do it from Ant either.

The [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) documentation says:

> -Xlint:none
>
> Disable all warnings not mandated by the Java Language Specification.

So it seems this kind of warning cannot be suppressed, because they are raised by the JLS directly.

What you can do is to:

1. use `@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation"}, {"unchecked"})` at the required positions
2. use some workaround to redirect the warning messages to `/dev/null`
3. try compiling from the command line with the `-Xlint:-unchecked -Xlint:-deprecation` arguments, maybe it is only an Ant-related issue.

Comment: -Xlint:-unchecked has no effect for me. It seems that there's simply no way to surpress warnings from the command line, despite what the documentation says. (-Xmaxwarns 0 has no effect either)

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation: Don't ignore your compiler's warnings.  The warnings are there for a reason.  My company's legacy codebase is moving towards a "treat warnings as errors and fail the build" model as we can expend the effort to fix warnings produced during our compile cycle.

In your case, the warning is:

```
warning: sun.reflect.Reflection is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

It has always been a warning to not import from `sun` packages as long as I can remember, because they're a non-public API.  There's even a [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) about it on the official Oracle Java site.

You haven't posted your actual code, so it's hard to provide further recommendations...What are you using in `sun.reflect.Reflection` that you couldn't also do through something in `java.lang.reflect`?

Comment: Because we have a button called "Crash the Server". This one uses the Unsafe class to modify memory at location 0 which leads to a JVM crash. This nice utility helps us to test the JVM crash recovery code. Also, it is faster examining stacktraces this way.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent deprecation warnings I tried to do it using JDK 6 and JDK 7.

With JDK 7, `@Deprecated` annotation does the work

With JDK 6, it does not work, neither adding `-Xlint:-deprecation` param works for me. The only way I managed to remove the warning was using the `@deprecated` [Javadoc Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html#javadoc_tag):

```
  /**
   * @deprecated
   */
  @Override
  public void removeValue(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
```