# How do you get *ant* to not print out javac warnings?

Tags: ant, warnings, javac

I just want the errors, and nothing else, to be printed out for now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<javac .... nowarn="on">
```

Note that this [does not disable *all* kinds of warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613857/cannot-stop-ant-from-generating-compiler-warnings).

Comment: You have an ant script with a "javac" tag in it, no?

Comment: Note that the correct syntax is nowarn="on", not nowarn="true". nowarn="true" is not working for me. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html