# How to suppress the proprietary API warning for sun.reflect.Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, suppress-warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot stop ant from generating compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613857/cannot-stop-ant-from-generating-compiler-warnings)

How to suppress this warning:

```
sun.reflect.Reflection is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

using [@SuppressWarnings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) in Oracles javac (1.6)?

According to [this blog](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/supported-values-for-suppresswarnings/) using `"all"` should work but it does not. Does anybody know the correct string?

Comment: Can't you use java.lang.reflect instead?

Comment: @assylias: 1) the other question is not answered either. 2) `java.lang.reflection` does not have `sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the

> -XDignore.symbol.file

option to the javac command line

hope this helps

EDIT
REF : [OPENJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/sctp/html/sctp6.html)

EXAMPLE 6

To compile your source you can either use the javac from JDK7 with -source 1.6 -target 1.6, or run the javac from your patched JDK6 with -XDignore.symbol.file=true. This flag is necessary because javac uses a symbol file to determine packages in the com/sun namespace and will not recognize the new sctp classes as they are not in this symbol file.

Comment: This seems to help but I have no idea why. What does this do? And why does it suppress warnings? And what of the things I probably do not want does it do?

Comment: Please refer to the edit

Comment: I did not get an error about a missing class but a warning about a proprietary API. How can an information about a "sctp" class (whatever his might be) changing the API being proprietary? But anyway...

Comment: hmmm.. not very sure myself but I faced similar issues sometime back and did some research and what I could make out of it was that the sun.reflect.Reflection package is not referenced from the symbol file(mentioned above) so it does not try to load that module and hence suppress the warning.. anyway.. not much information available..but this does the trick. :-)