# Suppress javac warning "...is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release"

Tags: java, javac

When I compile the Spring JDBC source on OS X with JDK 1.7.0, I get this warning:

```
warning: CachedRowSetImpl is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

How do I suppress the warning message during a compile?

I already know and use Java's @SuppressWarning annotations. I'm looking for the specific use of this to suppress the warning I've described.

My question specifically is, in this line of code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("valuegoeshere")
```

what should "valuegoeshere" be replaced with?

EDIT: People, I know that it is best to avoid the code that leads to the warning. And usually that would be my approach. However I'm compiling third-party code here which I don't want to rewrite. I just want to add the correct annotation to suppress the warning, so that warnings I can actually do something about don't get buried.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale I don't know, I'm not using Eclipse. I'm compiling from a shell script using Oracle's Java compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot stop ant from generating compiler warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613857/cannot-stop-ant-from-generating-compiler-warnings)

Comment: Rather than suppress the warning, in the base of the Base64 encoder, why not [use the Java 8 supplied encoder rather than the proprietary API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This particular warning [cannot be suppressed](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6476630). At least not officially.

> The warning about proprietary API means that you should not
> use the API which causes the warning.  Sun does not support
> such API and the warning will not be suppressible.

If you're particularly determined, you can use the highly undocumented [`javac -XDignore.symbol.file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4070685/68587) flag which will compile your program against Sun's internal `rt.jar` rather than the public-facing symbol file `ct.sym`. `rt.jar` doesn't produce this warning.

Comment: It is not true now (jdk7+), see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855700/suppress-javac-warning-is-internal-proprietary-api-and-may-be-removed-in-a-f/42406330#42406330

Comment: It still works with Java 8, but not with Java 9. Has anyone found a solution working with latest Java 9 build?

Comment: I was able to get rid of it with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966719/714112

Answer (score 26):

If you are using maven, you might be interested in adding the following to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Any ideas why not?

Comment: It works for me using Oracle's Java 8 compiler. I just verified with a single-file project that it reported a warning without the configuration above, and then the warning went away after I added the section above. My answer isn't explicit about this, but did you put that section inside `build`:`plugins`? Otherwise, I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Actually, after further inspection, it appears to be coming from the maven-processor-plugin:

maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) @ project ---
diagnostic: /home/project/src/main/java/Test.java:8: warning: sun.misc.Signal is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.misc.Signal;

Comment: Setting outputDiagnostics to false fixes this. Similar problem referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634008/maven-processor-plugin-to-ignore-undefined-symbols

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm glad you found a fix.

Comment: for these cases when this does not work, just add `<fork>true</fork>` to the configuration

Comment: Can you please tell me which plugin I can add for the ivy.xml file.

Answer (score 18):

see this answer

> [Cannot stop ant from generating compiler Sun proprietary API warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613857/cannot-stop-ant-from-generating-compiler-sun-proprietary-api-warnings/34966719#34966719)

Testing code

```java
@SuppressWarnings("sunapi")
sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl test;
```

compiling command line

```
javac test.java -Werror -Xlint:sunapi -XDenableSunApiLintControl
```

or

```
javac test.java -Werror -Xlint:all -XDenableSunApiLintControl
```

compile passed with no any warning

remove the `SuppressWarnings` tag and compile again:

an error is reported then

```
test.java:4: warning: X509CertImpl is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl test;
                     ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning
```

Answer (score 8):

Reference its interface [CachedRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/rowset/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) not the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not possible here. I'd need to write my own implementation of CachedRowSet for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

I tried

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
```

but that didn't work.

So I resorted to a horrible, horrible kludge which I don't recommend in general, but in this specific case made the warning go away. I used reflection to instantiate a new instance of the com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl class.

I replaced this line, which caused the warning:

```
    return new CachedRowSetImpl();
```

with this block:

```
    try {
        final Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl");
        return (CachedRowSet) aClass.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Please don't do this in your own code without first considering any other option.

Comment: and what exactly is wrong with that code? Seems just fine

Answer (score 2):

I acknowledge that this answer is a late harvest, and you will have solved your problem. But I got stuck in the same problem as you, and researching I found this solution.

**Why happens?**

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html

**Is this behavior wrong?**

No, its a warning telling us that ChachedRowSetImpl does not belong to the public interface, therefore compatibility is not guaranteed.

**Workaround**

The following code snippet creates a `CachedRowSet` object by using a `RowSetFactory` which is created by the `RowSetProvider`:

```
RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
CachedRowSet rowset = factory.createCachedRowSet();
```

This creates a `CachedRowSet` object from the implementation class `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`. It’s equivalent to the following statement:

```
CachedRowSet rowset = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();
```

However, it’s recommended to create a `CachedRowSet` object from a RowSetFactory because the reference implementation may be changed in future

Answer (score 0):

Try the javac option

```
-Xlint:none
```

If you compile from an IDE, it should have an option to disable warnings.

This will disable ALL warnings that are not a part of Java Language Specification. So for example "unchecked" warning will not be blocked.

Comment: I don't want to suppress all warnings. Just the one specific instance of one specific warning type.

Comment: @Steve then you have no other option but to follow Boris's answer.