# How do I suppress warnings about the Unsafe API when compiling with SBT

Tags: sbt, unsafe

I have a project including both Java and Scala sources. The Java sources include one file which uses the `sun.misc.Unsafe` API. We are well aware of the risks of using this API and want to suppress the warnings in this file. However, we also want to treat warnings as errors on the rest of the Java and Scala code.

My `build.sbt` includes these lines:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    // ...
    Compile / javacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-Xlint:all",
      "-Werror",
      "-XDenableSunApiLintControl"
    ),
    Compile / fork := true,
    Compile / javaOptions += "-XDenableSunApiLintControl",
    // ...
  )
```

I understand [from an SO comment on a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855700/suppress-javac-warning-is-internal-proprietary-api-and-may-be-removed-in-a-f#comment65477086_19503679) that I must fork a new JVM for `-XDenableSunApiLintControl` to take effect. For this reason, I specified `Compile / fork := true` and respecified the option in the `Compile / javaOptions`.

Unfortunately, I still see the warning reported as an error.

My Java file starts this way:

```java
package is.hail.annotations;

import sun.misc.Unsafe;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

@SuppressWarnings("sunapi")
public final class Memory {
```

Which successfully suppresses the warnings when using Gradle with

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all" << "-Werror" << "-XDenableSunApiLintControl"
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.fork = true // necessary to make -XDenableSunApiLintControl work
}
```

---

How do I enable suppression of the `sun.misc.Unsafe` API in SBT?

Comment: fwiw, I'm not having this problem here, even with `Compile / fork` being false: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/9370