# Is it possible to tell -Werror to ignore a certain class or a certain warning during Java compilation?

Tags: java, gradle, compilation, warnings, suppress-warnings

I use Gradle to build my Java project with the following settings to treat warnings as errors:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Werror"
}
```

Now we would like to work on some experimental research stuff in a certain class (let's call it `Experimental.java`) which throws some warnings (`warning: XYZ is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release`). This leads to the problem that the whole project does not build.

Can we exclude a certain class from being checked based on `-Werror` (i.e., "don't check `Experimental.java`")? Or can we tell `-Werror` to ignore a certain warning (i.e., "don't treat `internal proprietary API` warning as error")? We don't want to turn off `-Werror` completely, other classes should still be treated that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966719/2938364) I came up with a solution.

First off, one has to add the compiler flag `-XDenableSunApiLintControl` and can then turn off "Sun internal warnings" using `-Xlint:-sunapi`.

My adjusted Gradle build file looks like the following:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.compilerArgs << "-XDenableSunApiLintControl" << "-Xlint:all" << "-Werror" << "-Xlint:-sunapi"
}
```