# Javac: Option to compile without notes

Tags: java, javac, compiler-warnings, compiler-options

Is there a compiler option for javac to compile without notes?

I know of:

- `-nowarn` : to not display warnings
- `-g:none` : to generate no debugging info

Notes are still generated with both of these. 
Is there a compiler option to not generate notes, too?

By 'notes' I mean compiler output such as:

```
Note: Exercise.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I use `javac 1.7.0_40`.

Comment: Didn't that Note itself gave you an option?

Comment: Compile with `-Xlint:unchecked` option. You should rather modify your code to remove unchecked operation.

Comment: as the note says, compiling with `Xlint:unchecked` gives more details on content of note itself, which is not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3):

Not really an javac option, but worth to mention...

If you don't want to display any compilation output.

```
in unix: javac ... > /dev/null

in windows: javac ... > NUL
```

After some research ([How can I suppress javac warnings about deprecated api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554538/how-can-i-suppress-javac-warnings-about-deprecated-api))

> "From what I can tell in the docs, you can't do it on the
>   command-line.
>
> According to the [`javac` documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), -Xlint:none only disables
>   warnings "not mandated by the Java Language Specification". It appears
>   that warning you of the use of deprecated APIs is managed by the
>   language spec.
>
> Your best option would be to fix the use of deprecated APIs. However,
>   an option would be to add the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`
>   annotation to the classes or methods that are using the deprecated
>   APIs."

And

> "Two possible ways:
>
> 1. don't use deprecated API
> 2. Use [@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html)