# How to use depricated function by avoiding warning

Tags: java, android

I know this question is asked several times.
My problem is to use a mute function which is depricated now. But the new solutions cannot be applied to lower versions. I have used this function within a if else loop as shown in the code given below. But while inspecting the code, it is showing a **Code maturity issue**. Is there any way to avoid this inspection issue.
Can I use any annotations or something like that?

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
        } else {
            audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        }
```

Hope to get a good solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the full text of the issue?

Comment: Simply suppress the warning by adding `@SuppressWarnings("..."` before your function signature.

Comment: I can't supress this warning. Rather i want to avoid this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I suppress javac warnings about deprecated api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554538/how-can-i-suppress-javac-warnings-about-deprecated-api)

Comment: If this method is deprecated that's the state. You either use the new method that is linked in the javaDoc ( in most cases ) or suppress the warning with the annotation. It is generally not recommended to use deprecated code, specially when if comes from a sdk, because they provide a new one in most cases that is better in some ways. Also you risk using a function that will be completely removed at some point, resulting in a broken software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SuppressWarnings annotation to ignore warnings. To ignore "deprecated" warning, you have to add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecated")` to your method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use deprecated method by using @SuppressWarnings anotation in java ,for Detail  refer [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941900/is-it-wrong-to-use-deprecated-methods-or-classes-in-java)